# Accessing the 2nd member of a class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a stack of divs that belong to a specific class, say tabs. and the semantic structure looks something like this:

```
<div class = "tabs" >_______</div>
<div class = "tabs" >_______</div>
<div class = "tabs" >_____</div>
```

It's easy to access the first and the last element of the div like

```
$('.tabs:first') or
$('.tabs:last')
```

but getting to the 2nd (and assuming there are multiple other divs inside then the all divs other than first or last) seems to yield a syntax error to me such as :

`$('.tabs:second') or $('.tabs:third')` do not work expectedly.

Can anyone pinpoint what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery `:first` selector documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

You'll notice that this is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification.
Also that `:first` is equivalent to `:eq(0)`, that means if you want to get the second element, you can do it with `:eq(1)`.

If you don't need a filter in the CSS selector, you can simply get the element with the [.eq method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this:

```
$('.tabs').eq(0) // get the first element
$('.tabs').eq(1) // get the second element
$('.tabs').eq(2) // get the third element
$('.tabs').eq(-2) // get the second to last element
$('.tabs').eq(-1) // get the last element
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, notice the index is zero-based:

```
$(".tabs:eq(1)");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `:eq(1)`?  It's zero-indexed :-P

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to do this, either using the `.eq()` method or the `:eq()` selector.

**The .eq() method:**

The way the jQuery documentation recommend you do this is by making use of the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
// eq() is zero-based, so this would get the second element
$('.tabs').eq(1)
```

A handy feature is that `.eq()` also can take a negative number, which causes the function to start from the end instead.

```
// This would take the second element from the end
$('.tabs').eq(-2);
```

**The :eq() selector**

jQuery also provide an [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, that basically work the same way the `.eq()` method does. So you could do this as well:

```
$('.tabs:eq(1)')
```

Notice that even though this work, it is preferred to use the `.eq()` method instead of the selector. The method has better performance in modern browsers and the `:eq()` selector does not support negative numbers, so it is somewhat more limited.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.eq(1)`?  It's zero-indexed :-P

Comment: @Rocket Sure, we could take the second element instead if that feels better for you :) Just took one as an example.